# Partial Differentiation in Polar?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

$$ r = e^{\theta} $$

This is the equation of a polar curve, I need to find $dy/dx$ of the curve in Cartesian. My approach was to express the above equation in terms of $x$, $y$ and $\theta$:

$$ x^2 + y^2 = e^{2\theta}$$

But I am confused because how do I deal with the $\theta$? It is a variable and is dependent on both $x$ and $y$. My first thought was to use partial derivatives in an attempt to make $\theta$ a constant but I don't really have an experience with them. Any tips?

Comment: To @ED2468: what is correct equation $e^\theta$ or $e^{2\theta}$?

Comment: Remember $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ so you have a parametrization of the curve in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: $ \displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{d\theta} \times \frac{d\theta}{dx}.$